# Playing audio and playing it some more

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game in unity 5 with C#.

So far ive managed to design the level and done some basic scripting.

Currently i have a trigger that spawns an object and want it to play and audio source once the user enters. However, because i want it to be a jump scare, the trigger is very small and currently the sound only plays IF i stay in the trigger.

The code I have is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject monster;
    public AudioSource aud; 
    public AudioClip piano; 

    void Start () 
    {
        monster.SetActive (false);
        aud = monster.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            monster.SetActive (true);
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(piano, monster.transform.position);
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){
        if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            monster.SetActive (false);
        }
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }

}
```

I was wondering if theres a way to **keep the sound playing even after the persons left the trigger**.

Thanks!

Comment: this problem is "horrific" !  :)

Comment: The first answer provided by @gjttt1 seems to work for me. I have on error which doesnt make sense but it doesnt cause the game to crash

Comment: you have huge problems.  (1) make a TOTALLY NEW GAME OBJECT, called "scare sound".  (2) on "scare sound", have the audio source.  (3) on "scare sound", have a small script called ScareHandler, it does nothing other than play the sound.  So you will have one function like "PlayScarySoundNow()".  You will have to handle all the logic in there.  unity is actually **much more difficult than everyone pretends**.  You are totally wasting your time trying to do it with the audio where it is now, unfortunately. It will never really work.  It's tough.  life is difficult with Unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GameObject audio is attached to is being destroyed before the audio finish playing. Using `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint` will create and destroy `Audiosource` which makes caching of `aud` to be useless. Also, If you have too many trigger GameObjects, that will be slow because of `GC`. Use `Coroutine` and wait for the audio to finish playing then destroy `gameObject`.

```
public GameObject monster;
public AudioSource aud;
public AudioClip piano;

void Start()
{
    monster.SetActive(false);
    aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (aud.isPlaying)
    {
        return; //Exit if Audio is already playing
    }

    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        monster.SetActive(true);
        aud.PlayOneShot(piano);
    }

}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        monster.SetActive(false);
    }
    StartCoroutine(waitForAudioThenDestroy());
}

IEnumerator waitForAudioThenDestroy()
{
    //Wait until we are done playing
    while (aud.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null;//Don't freeze
    }

    //We are no longer playing audio so we can destroy this gameObject now
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I did try the above method, however it doesnt destroy the trigger. and ive i walk backwards the monster respawns and the sound plays agai

Comment: wouldnt it be better to only use OnTriggerEnter and start the coroutine there if this only should happen once in the game anyway?

Comment: This is simple script that should work. You are probably doing something else. Put `Debug.Log("Waiting for audio to finish");` in the`while (aud.isPlaying)` loop. Put `Debug.Log("Done Playing")` before the `Destroy(this.gameObject);` then run this with only one instance of Spawner script. Paste your log on pastebin.com and link me there.

Comment: @yes I think he wants to destroy when the object is out of the trigger. I am guessing this according to his original code.

Comment: @Kingspud When do you want the object to destroy? When the object enters the trigger area? When the object leaves the trigger area after entering?

Comment: @programmer I think that's the only downside of this method. If the player leaves and then re-enters the trigger area before the clip is finished playing then the monster will spawn again/sound played again. I think you would need to add a `hasBeenTriggered` bool to fix it!

Comment: What my idea is, when the player enters the trigger a monster appears and as soon as they leave the trigger the monster disapppears, so a jump scare. The trigger is very small. I want the sound to play as soon as they enter the trigger, Lets say the sound is 3 seconds long and it takes them 1 second to enter and leave the trigger. I still want the final 2 seconds of the sound to play when they leave the trigger

Comment: @gjttt1 that should still work. The coroutine should wait for the current sound to finish playing then destroy the current gameObject. This post is getting long for no reason.

Comment: @Kingspud  I think that your problem is where you are spawning `Spawner` from. Can you put **EDIT** in your question and post the code where you are spawning `Spawner` script/object?

Comment: @Programmer Think about if he walks out of the Triggerzone when the audio is still playing. Then the Spawner is still there as `Destroy(this.gameObject)` has not been called yet. Then if he walks back into the Triggerzone before the audio is finished playing it will call `OnTriggerEnter` again and will set the monster to active and play the sound again. I'm almost certain that that is the problem that he is now facing.

Comment: @Kingspud **Edited my original post to show latest code** But that's not my code. That's gjtt1's answer. Replace your code with the code in my answer. Just copy it and paste it so that there is no typo. I modified the code just copy it directly and paste it.

Comment: @gjttt1 if that is the problem he is having, he should add    if `(aud.isPlaying)
        {
            return; //Exit if Audio is already playing
        }` to `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {` before any other code in that function. Just modified my answer to include fix for that if that is the problem he is having.

Comment: Yes I think that would make your answer complete. @Kingspud check out the edit and accept this answer if it works!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that  you are deleting the `gameObject` that the `AudioSource` is attached to in the `OnTriggerExit` function before the sound can finish playing. An easy way to fix this would be to attach the `AudioSource` to your `monster` instead and access it from there. This will work because you are not Destroying the monster. I think all you would need to change would be this (after you have moved the `AudioSource` to the `monster` in the inspector):

```
void Start () 
{
    monster.SetActive (false);
    aud = monster.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
```

Another, even quicker, way to sort this would be to call [`PlayClipAtPoint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html) in your `OnTriggerEnter` method:

```
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {
        monster.SetActive (true);
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(piano, monster.transform.position);
    }

}
```

As this is a static method, you can then remove the `aud` audio source entirely. The `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint` works by instantiating a new `AudioSource` component in the world at a point you specify (`monster.transform.position`), playing the clip specified (`piano`), and then deleting the `AudioSource` once the clip is finished playing.

Edit: also, I don't think your `OnTriggerEnter` method needs the return type of `IEnumerator` as you aren't using the `yield` keyword anywhere in the method. you could simply change it to have a `void` return type. This won't effect the functionality of your code in anyway though.

Edit2: I foolishly overlooked the fact that you are setting the monster to be inactive. I think your best option in this case is to use `PlayClipAtPoint`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the audio still stops once ive left the trigger

Comment: which method did you try?

Comment: If you use the `PlayClipAtPoint` way of doing it then that is the only line you need to change in your code.

Comment: @Kingspud I've edited my answer. The second half is the part that works. i.e everything after "Another, even quicker, way to sort this"

Comment: @Kingspud Change `IEnumerator` for `void` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function definition.

Comment: That works but now it says `UnassignedReferenceException: The variable monster of Spawner has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the monster variable of the Spawner script in the inspector.` eventhough ive assigned it in the inspector part

Comment: @Kingspud hmmh that's strange if you have assigned it in the inspector. On a side note, check out the other answer. Although my method should work, the other answer is a better way of doing this.

Comment: I did try the above method, however it doesnt destroy the trigger. and ive i walk backwards the monster respawns and the sound plays again